# SQL macros in Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there a way to write a SQL Macro(PL/SQL or user defined functions) in Spark SCALA and use it in Spark SQL.

Example Macro -

```
CREATE Function getDeptEmployee(text IN TEXT)
RETURN TEXT
IS name TEXT
Begin 
select employee_name into name from department where departmentId = text
RETURN(name)
End
```

So I can use this getDeptEmployee in a query. I think I can't use the udf as I can't use the sqlContext.

Comment: can you share example data and expected output? SO is not tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can register any udf using

```
sqlContext.udf.register("getDeptEmployee", getDeptEmployee _)

def getDeptEmployee(text: String): String = {
    val spark2 = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .getOrCreate()
    val id = spark2.sqlContext.sql(s"select employee_name into name from department where departmentId = '$text' LIMIT 1").collect()(0).getString(0)
    id
}
```

But consider using joins in your original query instead of udfs that call spark context (udfs that don't call it are pretty fine and fast)

Comment: This question is about Spark SQL, not "running spark sql from a program".